# Cannot Access Url issue with Seeding database

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision

I'm currently using the GCP vision API to automate writing a seed file to a db and I am running into an error that hasn't shown up before.
Error Message:
"image-annotator::error(12): We can not access the URL currently. Please download the image and pass it in."

I know about sending in base_64 images but my site is using remote images and downloading, converting, and then storing each image isn't feasible in this scenario. I've also checked that the URL being sent in is a valid photo and that it was a JPEG.

The IMAGE_PROPERTIES request has worked when making promised calls on a small scale and now it is returning this error on the first call, if anyone knows something about this I'd appreciate it greatly!

Comment: UPDATE: There are specific url types that GCP just does not support and it seemed to be as simple as that, but sometimes it works, sometimes it bugs out.

Go get a coffee, talk about the latest political scandal and come back hopefully the API has 'refreshed'.
Not more commentary on the actual performance of IMAGE_PROPERTIES of this API bc it sees the least traffic amongst the of Vision features.